# How can I test whether a list is sorted with AssertJ

Tags: java, assertj

Given

```
List<Integer> list = ...
```

I would like to test with AssertJ whether it is sorted. Something like:

```
assertThat(list).isSorted()
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AssertJ offers out of the box [`isSorted()`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractListAssert.html#isSorted()) and [`isSortedAccordingTo(Comparator)`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractListAssert.html#isSortedAccordingTo(java.util.Comparator)) for list assertions:

```
List<String> strings = List.of("abc", "DEF");

assertThat(strings).isSorted(); // fails as "abc" is after "DEF" lexicographically
assertThat(strings).isSortedAccordingTo(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER); // succeeds
```

Comment: In case somebody else faces the same issue: I was testing `assertThat(CollectionObject).isSorted()`, which doesn't compile. I should have done something like: `assertThat(ListObject).isSorted()`.

Answer (score 0):

> import com.google.common.collect.Ordering;

And

> assertTrue(Ordering.natural().isOrdered(list));

Comment: The question is about AssertJ but `assertTrue` probably comes from the testing framework (JUnit / TestNG)